# How to write a query that would leave 1 row out

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a set of data that looks like this I want to remove one row for each of the debnrs that has a p in it for type.  I don't care which one.  The two rows with P in the type are identical except for the date.  How would I select just one with a P in the type.

```
debnr           docno      date            type  num       amount

 4          NULL    2013-08-29 07:26:25.000 P   1761        -12
 4          NULL    2013-09-12 00:00:00.000 P   1761        -12
 4          168371  2013-08-29 00:00:00.000 I     168371    12
 5          NULL    2013-10-11 09:24:58.000 P   7287        -24
 5          NULL    2013-10-14 00:00:00.000 P   7287        -24
 5          170366  2013-10-11 00:00:00.000 I     170366    24
 6          NULL    2013-10-24 00:00:00.000 P   4023        -465
 6          NULL    2013-10-24 09:42:18.000 P   4023        -465
 6          171095  2013-10-24 00:00:00.000 I     171095    465
 7          NULL    2013-12-16 00:00:00.000 P     171502    -394.2
 7          NULL    2013-12-16 00:00:00.000 P   6601        -394.2
 7          171502  2013-10-30 00:00:00.000 I     171502    394.2
```

how would I get it to look like this.

```
 4          NULL    2013-09-12 00:00:00.000 P   1761        -12
 4          168371  2013-08-29 00:00:00.000 I     168371    12
 5          NULL    2013-10-14 00:00:00.000 P   7287        -24
 5          170366  2013-10-11 00:00:00.000 I     170366    24
 6          NULL    2013-10-24 09:42:18.000 P   4023        -465
 6          171095  2013-10-24 00:00:00.000 I     171095    465
 7          NULL    2013-12-16 00:00:00.000 P   6601        -394.2
 7          171502  2013-10-30 00:00:00.000 I     171502    394.2
```

Comment: Use either the min or max date and add a group by clause.

Comment: when using that, debnr 7 would still return with 2

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark:

```
select 
  debnr,
  docno,
  max(date),
  type,
  num,
  amount

from magical_table
group by
  debnr,
  docno,     
  type,
  num,
  amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `GROUP` and use an aggregate given your sample above, if however the `amount` field weren't identical, for instance, then you could use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this to avoid needing an aggregate:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *
                    ,CASE WHEN TYPE = 'P' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY debnr ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
                          ELSE 0 
                     END AS RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RN <= 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0dac9/9/0)

The `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` could be changed to any field, that's just one way to get an arbitrary result if you don't want a min/max.

Answer (score 0):

Want you line with type "I" ungrouped ?

```
select debnr, docno, max(date), type,  num,  amount
  from magical_table 
  where type = "P"
  group by debnr, docno, type, num, amount
  UNION
  select debnr, docno, date, type,  num,  amount
  from magical_table 
  where type = "I"
```